# asp.net mvc viewdata tempdata variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

tempdata variables works like a session variables?

basically i want to do is to when the form loads for the first time the variables should be empty. but the variable should be persisted until i am on that form.

the form contains searching with a submit button as well as the paging .

basically my ques is to use what approach should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TempData vs. Session has been covered before:

[When to use TempData vs Session in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc)

I'm not quite sure I follow the rest of your question, though.  But I suspect that link may provide you with enough information for more research on the subject to make a more informed decision.  (It may also get you closed as a duplicate.  I would have put it in a comment, but wanted to be more verbose.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what your looking for is something simular to ViewState. Model binding is what you want to look at in MVC.

Comment: I agree, looking at Model binding is crucial