# Why my TempData is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I fill the model and the TempData

```
private const string MyTempModel = "MyTempModel";

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Abm()
        {
            var modelo = DependencyContainer.Instance.Resolve<MyModel>();
            modelo.Name = "Maxi" ;
            modelo.LastName = "Dam";
            TempData[MyController.MyTempModel] = modelo;

            return View(modelo);
        }
```

And here I want to get the values

```
 [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Save()
            {
                var model = TempData[MyController.MyTempModel] as MyModel;
                return View(model);
            }
```

What I'm doing wrong? I lose all the values...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TempData` will be around for the life the current request and the next request only...

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use session if you want the data to persist over several requests.

Check this thread for more info

- [When to use TempData vs Session in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc)