# passing in an additional parameter with the model to a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Still learning Mvc so sorry if this question is a bit weird.
I am passing the model in my Controller method and want to pass an additional parameter.

what I want to achieve is something like this but the parameter overload does not allow for the 'additional' parameter.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitCall", "Home", new { Id = Model.ProductDetail.ProductId }))
```

and then in the controller

```
public ActionResult SubmitCall(ViewModel model, int Id)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("DetailViewById", model, new {productId = Id});//not allowed
    }
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only intention is to redirect the client to another URL then the above scenario is not the right way to achieve this.

**RedirectToAction** will send a HTTP 302 with the Location information generated from your route information (again, in your case this would be the URL to **DetailViewById** with **productId** as a parameter or part of the URL - depends on your route configuration).

If you need to persist the **ViewModel** that is submitted by the client and operate on it once the user is requesting your redirected action, then i would suggest to use **[TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422930/using-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-best-practice)** which is designed for between-request persistence of such data.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the ViewModel is a combination of what you have coming back from database (DTO) + extra bits and pieces you need TO and FROM View.

So in my opinion, you should add this extra property to your Viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

Create an anonymous object for parameters:

```
return RedirectToAction("DetailViewById",
    new {
            productId = Id,
            model.Property1,
            model.Property2,
            ...
        });
```