# How to use sessions,Tempdata in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am working on asp.net with mvc 4 architectute. Here i have two controller Display and SessionEx. In Display Controller i have an method like below

```
public ActionResult SessionExample()
{
    TempData["FortheFullRequest"] = "FortheFullRequest";

    string v = Session["Session1"].ToString();

    ViewData["Myval"] = "ControllertoView";

    ViewBag.MyVal = "ControllertoView";

    Session["Testing1"] = "Testing Session";

    return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction", "SessionEx");
}
```

In the SessionEx controller i have the method as below

```
public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
{
    string str1 = Convert.ToString(Session["Testing1"]);
    string str2 = Convert.ToString(TempData["FortheFullRequest"]);

    return View();
}
```

I am debugging the project and i have also used watch to look at the gets stoted in tempdata and session. In the start the appropriate value in both session and tempdata but when the cursor reaches at RedirectToAction method all values gets stored in session and tempdata becomes null.Please help me someone here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data that will be used after a redirect is made to another action method, then use `Session`.

TempData is mainly for one-time, short-lived, requests as discussed in this [`this SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422930/using-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-best-practice)

You are likely finding that the data in TempData is not there after you have redirected to `SomeOtherAction()`, which is by desing with how `TempData` works.

To be honest, I never use TempData, I don't see the point myself.

Comment: I have used session to store value but when the control passes to the destination the values becomes null.

Comment: When you execute this line `string str1 = Convert.ToString(Session["Testing1"]);` is the value always `NULL`?

Comment: Yes when the control just passed from source controller the values becomes null.

Comment: That's odd. I don't know why that is the case. The one reason it owuld be `NULL` is if the session timeout and was restarted. But if you're getting `NULL` all the time, I'm not sure why that would be the case. Sorry.

Comment: Even i am not understanding the reason why this is happening but i am facing this problem for whole day that when the destination controller comes the values is always null

Comment: I have solved it by own. Actually i have not used the used the namespace   "using System.Web.SessionState;"  which is required for controlling the session state.