# How to pass a static value of field(View1) to another field in (View2) in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi can you help in sending a static value of the field in another view field..

so when the user clicked the button it will directly go to the page

my view page of the static value

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Customer</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "5", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Pay" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }
```

to this view

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
       }

      <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

Controller 1

```
        public ActionResult Pay(Payment apsp)
    {

        decimal amount = apsp.Amount;

        Payment pay = new Payment
        {

            Amount = amount

        };


        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

Model

```
public decimal Amount{ get; set; }
```

Comment: what field you want to send ? to which view ?

Comment: You can use either use a hidden field which holds your static value, put the static value as part of the form action url or even in the controller receiving the form.

Comment: I already edit it,

Comment: @MisamidFloride What static value you want to send. You need to have it in a form field and have your action method read and resend it to the next view

Comment: In view one I have a field for price, it already have a value, so I want to send that value to another field in another view

Comment: show us the controller's action

Comment: Your "question" has nothing to do with views, it's about your controllers and models.

Comment: I already edit it, with controller 1 and model, I dont'have yet the code in controller 2 because I don't know how pass the value in the view 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your Pay action method returns a RedirectResult, which is basically a **302** response which tells the browser to make a new HTTP GET call to the `Create` action method url. If you want to pass some data, you should return the view instead of this redirect result and pass the view model to the View method call.

So replace

```
 return RedirectToAction("Create");
```

with

```
return View("Create",pay);
```

Also there is no reason to create a new object if you are only reading one property and assigning it to same object type.

```
public ActionResult Pay(Payment apsp)
{
   return View("Create",apsp);
}
```

But from your question, It looks like your first view and second view are strongly typed to different view models. For the above code to work, Both should be strongly typed to same view model (as you are passing the same object of `Payment`)

Note. It is possible to pass (minimal) data via ReidrectToAction method call. Read the below post for more information about different ways to achieve that.

[How do I include a model with a RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction/11209320#11209320)

Comment: it will get the value of the Pay View into the Create view,right??

Comment: Don't need any code to the Create Controller? to retrieve the value of the Pay Controller?

Comment: It will work if your view models are same from both the views. See the update in the answer.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot it works fine,

Comment: note that: The standard with MVC (PRG pattern) is post your data, If there is an error return View() otherwise return RedirectResult. On this case I will not recommend to return View especially that the model is a "payment".

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you know how the HttpPost and HttpGet work.

You can pass your viewmodel via [TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427009/1638261) like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Pay()
{
    return View(new Payment());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pay(Payment payment)
{
    TempData["Payment"] = payment;

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    if (TempData["Payment"] == null) throw new Exception("Error");

    var payment = TempData["Payment"] as Payment;

    return View(payment);
}
```