# Difference in Forms Authentication between asp.net and asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there really any difference between how Forms Authentication work in asp.net and asp.net MVC applications ?

Comment: Not really. Authentication works the same. Authorization works differently. In MVC you set permissions to controller methods and in webforms you set permissions to files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. They both are using Core ASP.NET Framework. Which contains Authentication, Membership, Session and cache managment. All these features work exatly the same in asp.net and asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

While both Web Forms and MVC use the same exact principles and mechanics in authentication, but we do not have server controls in MVC, thus there are some different things to pay attention to.  In MVC you will see the [Authorize] attribute in which you will decorate methods with.

Regarding the Sessions,  TempData is a very lightweight session used for redirects see [When to use TempData vs Session in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc).

In MVC a lot of careful thought had to be be put into the use of sessions.  MVC has a temp ,   also regarding session, here is an very good stackoverflow quesiton and answer on using it  [Session variables in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc)