# Pass JSON from controller to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, model-view-controller

I am wondering and experimenting, can someone here can tell me how to pass a json from a controller action to another controller without using the session variable?? i am avoiding session because of confidentiality of data thanks.. Hope someone could help me

Comment: in the context of a single request?  or is the 2nd controller supposed to get this json after a seperate request is made to the server?

Comment: @RobertLevy to the 2nd controller. i want to retrieve the json from the first controller to the second one

Comment: You didn't actually answer my question

Comment: at a second request, lets say that the first controller has a request to the server and it needs to pass the json to another one.. sorry if i dont get it

Answer (score 1):

Use return RedirectToAction() and pass the json as action method argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **TempData** instead of the **Session**  to persist data across a redirection.

Comment: TempData is session, so it doesn't meet the question requirements. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: That's right, the data is persisted between requests but not shared!

Comment: yeah tempdata is like a session.. it cannot contain data that are to be sensitive and it also adds amount in slowing the app(???)

Comment: i am trying to add to the request context so it cannot be seen on the browsers session storage. help please