# How to maintain data between Get and Post Method for same view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am having this sample code

```
        public ActionResult SampleView()
        {
            TempData["datetime"] = "Tempdata:  " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

            ViewBag.datetime = "ViewBag:   " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

            ViewData["datetime"] = "ViewData:  " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

            return View();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SampleView(int? x) // 'x' is dummy variable, no use
        {
            string datetime1 = TempData["datetime"].ToString();

            string datetime2 = ViewBag.datetime;

            string datetime3 = ViewData["datetime"].ToString();    

            return RedirectToAction("SampleView");
        }
```

But none of the above retain the values between GET and POST. Any Solution ?

Comment: Try searching. TempData is for redirects, and redirects only.

Comment: I tried TempData in above case, but giving me error -> 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: Can you please provide me the link where  I can find the answer ?

Comment: See duplicate, [When to use TempData vs Session in ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc).