# Passing a value from a JsonResult method to another method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In my HomeController I have the following method:

```
public JsonResult AjaxTest(Position postData)
{
        Session["lat"] = postData.Lat;
        Session["lng"] = postData.Long;

    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How can I have lat and lng in my Index method?

It is `public async Task<ActionResult> Index()` , if it matters.

The script in the view that is retrieving and passing the user's current coordinates:

```
var x = document.getElementById("positionButton");

(function getLocation() 
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}());

function showPosition(position) 
{
    if (position == null) alert('Position is null');
    if (position.coords == null) alert('coords is null');

    $('#lat').text(position.coords.latitude);
    $('#long').text(position.coords.longitude);

    var postData = { Lat: position.coords.latitude, Long: position.coords.longitude };

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "@Url.Action("AjaxTest", "Home")",
        //dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData)

    });
}
```

I need to be able to have the user's current lat/long to get the distance to another position.
lat and lng are declared as public variables, so why do they stay 0 when trying to use the coordinates inside the Index method?

Edit, here is the Index method:

```
public object x;
     public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
            {


                x = Session["lat"];


                return View(parkingLot);
            }
```

Comment: Are you accessing them in the same request?

Comment: I am not sure, after Index loads and gets the coordinates, it sends it to the JsonResult.

Comment: Try passing postData as an object, not a string. data: postData. Another thing to check... Have you set a debugger on your javascript to make sure your Lat and Long are not 0 there?

Comment: I made that change you said, what do I have to modify in the method? No I did not set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables are declared in your controller, that could explain why they are zero.

Controllers are created on a per-request basis. So if you hitting `AjaxTest` and setting the lat/long, when the `JsonResult` gets returned to the ajax call, the controller with your variables is disposed. Try using `Session` instead of variables. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: So I changed it to Session["lat"] = postData.Lat; and then in the Index controller I use x = Session["lat"]; ? (public object x) because it doesnt work Not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: I put a breakpoint but x remains null, I did something wrong I think

Comment: In the AjaxTest action, is postData null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129833/discussion-between-jb06-and-crystyxn).

Comment: I can't use chat here at work, I can help more once I leave if you haven't figured it out already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TempData` to put your data in `AjaxTest` action like this:

```
public ActionResult AjaxTest(Position postData)
{
        this.TempData["lat"] = postData.Lat;
        this.TempData["lng"] = postData.Long;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And in index action you can retrieve your data like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var lat = this.TempData["lat"];
    var lng = this.TempData["lng"];
    return View(parkingLot);
}
```

[When to use TempData vs Session in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @crystyxn var lat and lng from index method is null?