# Creating a shared property available in all method across controller C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, static

I'm trying to implement a shared property in my C# controller where I've defined it like this:

```
public string guid;
    public string _gu_id
    {
        get { return guid; }
        set { guid = value; }
    }

public ActionResult ActionFirst()
{
 _gu_id = something...;
}

public ActionResult ActionSecond()
{
// checking now if the _gu_id is !=null
if(_gu_id!=null)
// do something here
}
```

Like this the property gets set in the first action but its value is not available in 2nd one...

I can declare it as static but that is not a solution as static variable should be avoided in web.. ?

Edit: To explain the problem in more details:

When the proprety _gu_id is set in first ActionFirst method, I need to be able to fetch its value in ActionSecond method, without using static variables...

Comment: XY problem. You have a problem, for which you think the solution is "create a member variable in my controller". Explain what problem you're trying to solve by that, because controllers are created per request. You probably need to store something in a session, token, header or elsewhere.

Comment: @CodeCaster The problem is as following: the variable GUID needs to be available in 2nd method when set in first method...I mentioned I could use static variable for this but I'm avoiding to use them since I've had very unpleasant experience with them...

Comment: @CodeCaster So upon setting the _gu_id variable in first method,  when 2nd method is called, I need to have the _gu_id value in second method which was set in first method...

Comment: _"the variable GUID needs to be available in 2nd method"_ - then stick it in a session, in a database, or pass it to the user for them to return upon the second request.

Comment: @CodeCaster Alrighty good point, session seems like the best solution, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you are redirecting to new action method of a new controller this a new request and you can't retain value from one request to another like the way you are looking for.

Rather use Session variable like this.

```
Session["guid"] = "YourValue";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are avoiding using persistent session variables (usually a good idea), MVC also offers [TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc) for hanging onto data between redirects.

Comment: You mean like TempData["Key"] ?