# Is it possible to retrieve and show view name dynamically in mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi i want to show the View name dynamically. i will explain my issue detaily.

I brought the menu in layout Page dynamically. Now what i  want is whatever name i click in menu list it redirect to that controller

**Dynamic Menu in Layout Page Eg format**

1) Accounts Master

1.1) Accounts

1.2) Accounts category

Now if i click accounts it go the accounts controller. At the same time i want to get that view name Accounts in controller. Then using session i can pass the name from to view to controller. Can any one tell me how i get the view name by selected value in menu layout page . Is it possible? In windows i saw this method .But i am struggling to do this in mvc.

**My model**

**Menu Model**

```
 public class Menu
  {
    public Menu()
    {
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        SubMenuItems = new List<SubMenuviewmodel>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    public List<SubMenuviewmodel> SubMenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

**SubMenuViewModel**

```
 public class SubMenuviewmodel
  {
    public string SubMenu { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string MainMenuName { get; set; }        
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string subid { get; set; }
 }
```

**MenuItem**

```
  public class MenuItem
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Menu ParentMenu { get; set; }
  }
```

**My Controller (Menu Controller)**

```
   public ActionResult SubMenu()
    {
        var menu = new Menu();

        var mainmenu = db.ApplicationNames.Select(e => new
        {
            uid = e.UID,
            mainmenuname = e.ApplicationName1
        }).ToList();

        var menuitemlist = new List<MenuItem>();
        for (var item = 0; item < mainmenu.Count();item++ )
        {
            var mainmenuitems = new MenuItem { Name = mainmenu[item].mainmenuname.ToString(),Id=mainmenu[item].uid };
            menuitemlist.Add(mainmenuitems);
        }
        menu.MenuItems = menuitemlist;
      //submenu
        var submenu = db.SubAplicationNames.Select(e => new
        {
            submenuuid = e.SubAplicationNameID,
            submenuname = e.SubMenuName,
            submenuparentidd = e.ApplicationID,
            mainmenuname=e.ApplicationName

        }).ToList();

        var submenulist = new List<SubMenuviewmodel>();
        for (var item = 0; item < submenu.Count();item++ )
        {
            var submenuitemslist = new SubMenuviewmodel { SubMenu = submenu[item].submenuname.ToString(),subid=submenu[item].submenuparentidd.ToString()
                ,ControllerName="Home",ActionName="Index" };
            submenulist.Add(submenuitemslist);
        }
        menu.SubMenuItems = submenulist;
            return View(menu);
    }
```

**My view**

```
 @model DynamicMenuLoading.Models.Menu
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
  @foreach (var MainMenu in Model.MenuItems)
 {
   <a href="#">
        <span>@MainMenu.Name</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
    @foreach (var SubMenu in Model.SubMenuItems.Where(x => x.subid == MainMenu.Id.ToString()))
    {
     <ul>
     <li><a href="@Url.Action(SubMenu.ActionName, SubMenu.ControllerName)"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>@SubMenu.SubMenu</a>

      //tried @Session["Name"]=@SubMenu.SubMenu;
    </li>           
    </ul>
    }
</ul>
 }

  public ActionResult Index()
   {
     var viewname =Session["Name"];
   }
```

Here this code is used to load the meny dyanmically in layout page. Now i want to pass the view name which i selected to controller. I tried to use session. That is get the name is session and tried to pass to controller . But it failed .Failed in the sense it give null values in controller and wrong output in view. Any one undertsand my issue and help me to resolve this problem.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with passing an additional parameter in the url like

```
href="@Url.Action(SubMenu.ActionName, SubMenu.ControllerName , new {Title=SubMenu.SubMenu})"
```

and in your action you can get the title

```
public ActionResult Accounts(string Title)
   {
     // your code here
   }
```

Comment: using this we can pass ID also using same method right

Comment: can you tell me how i pass this Viewname to view from controller and show in view?

Comment: use `ViewBag.Title=Title;` and in view `<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>`

Comment: Yes I also tried to use session which is better  viewbag it session

Comment: ViewBag is better since you will only use this value in view not anywhere else

Comment: No I want use in same view and another action in same controller

Comment: you can use TempData you can check this [TempData vs Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500402/when-to-use-tempdata-vs-session-in-asp-net-mvc)