# Page.EnableSessionState equivalent in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state

With ASP.NET WebForms it is possible to set the session state mode in the page directive:

```
<%@ Page EnableSessionState="true|false|ReadOnly" %>
```

Is the same configuration also possible in ASP.NET MVC (e.g. per controller or per action) and if so, how?

(In other words: can I disable or set to read-only session state per controllers/actions? I assume having the session state read/write will result in some overhead, so it might be useful if session state could be turned off if not required.)

Comment: This setting has no effect in an ASP.NET MVC application. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: updated question

Comment: I see. Next question: why do you need to disable or set read-only session state per controller/action?

Comment: Well if I know that my controller or action does not need any session state, then I'd like to turn it off (especially if this results in some performance improvement).

Comment: @M4N - you're right, read/write session state has the overhead of single-threading requests on a per-session basis. In other words a single user can only make one call to the web server at a time if the session is in read/write mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Session state per-request in ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464203/disable-session-state-per-request-in-asp-net-mvc) and [Enable / disable session state per controller / action method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250940/enable-disable-session-state-per-controller-action-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that with ASP.NET MVC 3 it will be possible to have session-less controllers, e.g. see [ScottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx) or [this post by Keith Dahlby](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/dahlbyk/archive/2010/12/06/renderaction-with-asp-net-mvc-3-sessionless-controllers.aspx).

Answer (score 20):

The ASP.NET MVC 3 equivalent to this appears to be the SessionState attribute, which you apply at the controller level - e.g.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute.aspx for more info.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235006/372926