# Do I need SessionStateModule in my ASP.NET MVC3 application hosted in Azure web role?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, session-state, httpmodule

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application I don't ever explicitly use `SessionStateModule` and so I assume I can just remove it by changing `web.config`. The application is hosted in Azure web role so I can't rely on per-instance session states anyway, can I?

Will removing this module likely break something or can I just remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, InProc will not work on Windows Azure. Here some options:

-Store session state using Sql Database

-Store session state using Table storage

-Store session state using Windows Azure Caching (recommended)

More information in here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx

https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/

Comment: Em... I don't actively want to store the session state. I wanted to know if I can just get rid of the module.

Comment: @sharptooth sorry. I read wrongly. TempData uses SessionState to store information. If you disable, it won't work.  http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/906b060113-Controlling-Session-Behavior-in-Asp.Net-MVC4.html http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=609   http://stackoverflow.com/a/4235006/1384539

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your application is designed and what features you are using.  If the application is 100% stateless, then session state can be removed.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer above, certain features will not work without Session State...the obvious answer is that remove it from web.config and test the application.