# ASP.Net session behavior in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, session-cookies, sessionid

I have a requirement to open a new window from Internet Explorer, but the new window should be in new asp.net session. It should not share the same session of previous opened window or the parent window. How can it be possible? Any thoughts?

I'm using window.open('mywindow.aspx') from parent page javascript to open new windows.

Comment: [Disable session on per-call basis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464203/disable-session-state-per-request-in-asp-net-mvc) may be helpful. (or add `EnableSessionState="false"` to *that* page's declaration (`<% Page ... EnableSessionState="false" %>`), too.

Comment: @Brad Christie but how does ASP.Net maintain a session? Isn't it via a cookie?  Is the cookie name always the same or can it be controlled somehow?

Comment: Honestly, without adding a dependance on, say, chrome's incognito window, I don't see a reliable way of separating sessions between windows. Anything you do to "kill" the session on one window will break the previous session. -- Also, it can be a number of ways (url [e.g. mySite.com/(S(...))/Default.aspx], cookie, both, neither, ...)

Comment: I agree with Brad's statement. The best you can do is use cookiless session but this brings security and other issues.