# Sessionless ASP.NET MVC 2 requests have sessions yet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session-less

As we need Async Ajax requests, it is required to disable session state. Web app is based on ASP.Net 4 - MVC 2.

I am aware of `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]`, however it is available in MVC 3+.

I am using the following method to route specific HTTP requests to a sessionless HTTPContext [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9241918/172163):

```cs
public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public System.Web.IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            requestContext.HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
            return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }
```

And in Global.asax:

```cs
routes.MapRoute( _
          Nothing, _
          "ajaxrequest/{id}", _
          New With {.controller = "AjaxEngine", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, _
             New SessionLessRouteHandler()
        )
```

Result?
The code compiles correctly, no errors in runtime. However, it does not change anything and in the HTTP Header of every single Ajax request I see a new set-cookie with a new session. For example, A browser may request 100 Ajax requests, and a new session will be generated for each request. And I never need a session for a static Ajax request. I see the following line in each Ajax request diagnosed by Chrome Network Monitor:

`Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=xlgxdzdxdeilws23prjns3cv; domain=mydomain.com; path=/`

Any idea why it does not work? And how can I avoid creating a new session for the requests?

- I have tried [the other solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/12/17/session-less-mvc-controller.aspx) by Rick, however the result is same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a mistake, `routes.MapRoute` accepts the new `IRouteHandler`, but it is inappropriate. You need to just set the RouteHandler using `routes.Add` instead of `routes.MapRoute` in Global.asax:

```cs
routes.Add(Nothing, New Route("ajaxrequest/{id}", New 
    RouteValueDictionary(New With { _
    Key .controller = "AjaxEngine", _
    Key .action = "Index", _
    Key .id = UrlParameter.Optional _
    }), New SessionLessRouteHandler()))
```

NOTE: By using ReadOnly sessionstate it continues to set the cookie. It is required to set it as `Disabled` in the RouteHandler class we defined.