# Session Timeout Refresh Meta Tag Reset .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to show a message when session end or redirect to a login page on .net web application.

I tried to use Session_End global.asax event but when this event fired, context is closed so I can't redirect to any page.

I tried too to send refresh meta tag but it refresh page even if the user is navigating on page, I mean, the refresh tag is never updating.

There is a method to do this? Can you help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JS to poll the server periodically (e.g. every minute using `setTimeout`) to ask `am I still logged in?`. If it gets `false` as a response, your JS can do whatever you'd like (show a message, redirect to the login page etc).

The server side implementation will be something like

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[DoNotExtendAuthentication]
public ActionResult IsAuthenticated(string url)
{
    var isAuthenticated = HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
     return Json(isAuthenticated); // change this line to whatever shape of JSON you want
}

public class DoNotExtendAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove(
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    }
}
```

*`DoNotExtendAuthenticationAttribute` is needed to effectively disable forms auth's sliding expiration logic.*

For your routing, be sure to use the [SessionlessHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846152/session-less-httphandler-and-routing-to-custom-handler-for-only-one-controller) so that it doesn't continually extend the `Session`.

Comment: But if you do this, the session is resetting everyTime javascript is making a call to the server...

Comment: Updated to be clearer about that @FranciscoMárquezChaves and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add **Timer** event with **ScriptManager**  and with timer **tick event** you can check your status.
if **session** has value then continue if not give them message or what ever you want.