# Asp.Net controller seemingly behaves as if single-threaded. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui, .net-6.0

(everything below initially written for .Net 5.0 but now targeting .Net 6.0)

Consider this Asp.Net controller used as REST Api :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
public class DebugController : ControllerBase {

    private readonly ILoggingWrapper log;

    public DebugController(ILoggingWrapper log) {
        this.log = log;
        log.Information("Constructor called");
    }

    private async Task Slow() {
        await Task.Delay(15000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    [Authorize()]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("testSlow")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TestSlow() {
        await Slow().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Ok();
    }

    [Authorize()]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("testFast")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TestFast() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I have a **Swagger** page configured, where I can call TestSlow and TestFast on demand.

### Experience #1

1. Open a browser tab with the Swagger page open,
2. Call only `TestSlow`

#### Result

The `DebugController` constructor enters immediately, then TestSlow starts immediately and returns after 15 seconds

### Experience #2

1. Open a browser tab with the Swagger page open,
2. Open another browser tab with the Swagger page open,
3. On the first Swagger page, call only `TestSlow`
4. Quickly switch to the other Swagger page, call `TestFast`

#### Result

- The `DebugController` constructor enters immediately, then TestSlow starts immediately
- When calling `TestFast`, and while `Testslow` is still running, The `DebugController` constructor enters immediately and TestFast starts immediately.

the two experiences above behave as I expect it : Asp.Net is multithreaded and calling one endpoint does not stop another client from calling another endpoint, even if the first endpoint is still being served to the first client.

### Experience #3 (the weird one)

1. Open a browser tab with the Swagger page open,
2. Open another browser tab with the Swagger page open,
3. On the first Swagger page, call only `TestSlow`
4. Quickly switch to the other Swagger page, call `TestSlow` there too

#### Result

- The `DebugController` constructor enters immediately, then `TestSlow` starts immediately
- When calling the *other* `TestSlow`, the Controller's contructor **is not called before the first call to TestSlow is entirely finished and has returned!**. In effect, the two calls to TestSlow happen sequentially.

**Why is that?**  Why does multithreading suddenly seem to "disappear" the moment I try to call the same endpoint twice, even though I do it from two different clients?

Comment: Have you tried the same experiments in Release mode?

Comment: Have you tried to do it without debugging (and use logging/time measurements to determine the behaviour)?

Comment: Do you have session state enabled? That's usually the culprit if you're seeing requests from the same browser being served serially rather than in parallel. *(NB: Two tabs in the same browser aren't "two different clients"; try calling from two different browsers instead.)*

Comment: Why are you using .ConfigureAwait(false)? That doesn't need to be done in an ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: just a nit-pick here... "async" does not equal "multithreading".  (Changes nothing about your question, though... async should be a non-blocking call.)

Comment: PeterCsala Guru Stron: No, I will try Release configuration.
Richard deeming : I don't jnow if I have sesssion state enabled, I'll investigate that.
Mason:  just a coding practice in my company, don't ask.
Pcalkins Indeed; here I'm expecting the multithreading to result from how Asp.Net manages controller instances, not from any specific async/await

Comment: Running in Release doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @RichardDeeming look at my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I most likely discovered by accident that **session state** disables *simultaneous* serving of the same endpoint called several times, as devised here:

[Disable Session state per-request in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464203/disable-session-state-per-request-in-asp-net-mvc)

So it appears that it isn't a multithreading problem, instead it's a web app configuration ("by design") problem.

**@Richard deeming :** Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.